# Smoke Flow Force Field isn't affecting Hair Particle System. How do I affect hair with a smoke flow force field?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, hair, force-fields

I have baked a simple **smoke-simulation** which is affected by a *wind force field*, and a *turbulence force field*.

It's looking great so far...

Now I add a simple **plane** with a **hair particle system** and a **smoke flow force field** and select the *smoke domain* with the simulation.

But I can't get it to work. The **hairs** only **react** to the wind and turbulence force fields, **not to the smoke flow force field**.

When I turn the wind and turbulence off in the Field Weight Settings, they don't move at all, although they should be affected by the smoke flow force field, right?

What am I missing here?

What I want in the end is something like this:

[image]

Working with Blender 2.83.2